# Antithetic Variables Approach

Tags: estimation, simulation

Given the function  $\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{x+1}\exp(x^2)$, I am trying to approximate the integral over $[1,5]$ using the [antithetic variables approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates) with five intervals.

First, from my understanding of the approach, I am unclear as to what intervals mean, since I would expect to need pairs of antithetic unit uniform samples, such as the standard $U$ and $1 - U$, so could someone explain the interval idea?

I am also unsure as to how to start this problem, as the integral is not unit uniform normalized.  Is this similar to importance sampling where I might need to create a "normalized pdf"?

Comment: Hint: this integral is (almost) the expected value of ${\sqrt X\over\sqrt{X+1}}\times\exp\left(X^2\right)$ for a well-chosen random variable. Which one?

Once you’ve answered this, I think you’ll understand the interval stuff. I think it is a bit surprising to call this ''antithetic'' though, but why not.

Comment: I believe that I am supposed to construct five estimates and then take the average of the five to get a final estimate.  So my real question is if, given the formula theta = (b-a)*g(a+(b-a)x) where b and a are different limits and x is a randomly sampled uniform unit value, does g need to be normalized over any interval?  So would it be fair to say that my first estimate is = sum((2-1)g(2+(2-1)xi))?

Comment: I think that instead of considering the antithetic method as "taking the average of various estimates", you should look at it as "increasing the sample size". In the case of the standard $U \mapsto 1-U$ transformation, a sample $u_1, \dots, u_n$ is augmented by $1-u_1, \dots, 1-u_n$.